# Using controllerProvider on abstract states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Take this example state definition:

```
.state('parent',
{
    abstract:true,
    url:'/parent',
    controller:'Child1Controller'
    templateUrl:'parent.html'
})
.state('parent.child1',
{
    url:'/{data:[0-9]{1,8}}',
    template:'child1.html'
})
.state('parent.child2',
{
    url:'/:otherData',
    template:'child2.html'
});
```

Child 1 is activated when the url is numeric (e.g. `/parent/1234`), otherwise, Child 2 is activated.

I want different controllers for each child state, for example `Child1Controller` should only be instantiated for `chid1` state. I don't want to set the controller on each child state because when the value of '/:data`or`/:otherData` change the same controller will get instantiated for each.

I only need the controller to change when switching between child states.

I wanted to use `controllerProvider`, but I can't see any data passed to it that I can use to know which child was activated.

Is that possible or should I just define a new parent route for the second child state?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

After your comment it become a little clearer. While I'm sure this problem could be prevented by refactoring (for example, cache loaded data, move processing functions to outside services) so that it would not matter how often the child controller is instantiated, there is another way.

You could wrap your child states in another layer of parent states that would have the controller property:

```
.state('customers', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/customers',
  templateUrl: 'customers.html'
})
.state('customers.child1wrap', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '',
  controller: 'Child1Controller',
  template: '<div ui-view></div>'
})
.state('customers.child1', {
  url: url:'/{data:[0-9]{1,8}}',
  templateUrl: 'child1.html'
})
.state('customers.child2wrap', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '',
  controller: 'Child2Controller',
  template: '<div ui-view></div>'
})
.state('customers.child2', {
  url:'/:otherData',
  templateUrl: 'child2.html'
})
```

This way you can change url parameters of `child1`, `child2` without re-instantiation of `Child1Controller`, `Child2Controller`.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I'm not sure I understand your setup correctly, e.g. why do you define `Child1Controller` on `parent` and not on `customers.child1`. Also, shouldn't `parent` be called `customers`, if you that state to be hierarchical parent of `child1`, `child2`?

Anyways, if these assumptions are correct, this the way I would organize those states:

```
.state('customers', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/customers',
  templateUrl: 'customers.html'
})
.state('customers.child1', {
  url: url:'/{data:[0-9]{1,8}}',
  controller: 'Child1Controller',
  templateUrl: 'child1.html'
})
.state('customers.child2', {
  url:'/:otherData',
  controller: 'Child2Controller',
  templateUrl: 'child2.html'
})
```

Comment: Hey. `customers` was a typo. The reason why I don't want to set the controller on the child state is that it gets instantiated on each child state change. I only want the controller to be instantiated once  when state changes happen between same child states. So, going to `/parent/hello` then to `/parent/test` would only instantiate `Child1Controller` once, then going to `/parent/123` would instantiate `Child2Controller`. If the next URL was `/parent/321`, then `Child2Controller` is already instantiated so it isn't re-instantiated.